# Topological dimension, is it local?

Tags: gn.general-topology, dimension-theory

Let $n\in\mathbb N$ and $X$ be a complete metric space.

> Assume that there is $\epsilon>0$ such that 
>   $$\dim B_\epsilon(x)\le n$$
>   for any $x\in X$.
>   Is it true that $\dim X\le n$?

- Here $\dim$ stays for [topological dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_covering_dimension).
- We do not assume that $X$ is separable!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [E]T.7.2.3 p. 484:

1] If a Normal topological space $X$ has a locally finite closed cover $(F_f)_{s\in S}$ and $dim F_s\leq n\ s\in S$ then $dim X \leq n$.

from the subspace theorem ([ED]p.216):

2] For any subspace $M$ of a strongly-hereditarily-normal space (in particular a metric space)  $X$ we have $dim M \leq dim X$

***In what  follow assume that any open $\epsilon'$-ball ($\epsilon'\leq\epsilon$) B as $dim$-dimention $n$***.

3] If $A\subset X$ contains a  open $\epsilon'$-ball and is contained in a open $\epsilon'$-ball ($\epsilon',\epsilon''\leq \epsilon$) then $dim A=n$

PROOF: From [2].

4]  There exist a locally finite covering of closed set $(F_s)_{s\in S}$ with $dim F_s\leq n$.

PROOF: COnsider the covering by all open $\epsilon/2$-balls, and let $(B_s)_{s\in S}$ a locally finite refinement ($X$ is paracompact), let $F_s:=Cl(B_s)$ then $(F_s)_{s\in S}$ is a locally finite refinement  of  the  open $\epsilon$-balls covering. Then as in [3] follow that $dim F_s=n$.

Then from [1] and [4]: $dim(X)\leq n$ and from [2]:  $n=dim B_\epsilon(x) \leq dim X$

[E]: Engelking, General Topology
[ED]: Engelking, Dimention theory

Comment: Thank you very much. 
It is strange that such basic statement needs to be proved.
I thought it should be a standard theorem.